# What is the armor movement penalty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The UESP's [Comparison [of Light Armor] to Heavy Armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Light_Armor#Comparison_to_Heavy_Armor) states, among its advantages, "Lighter and less movement penalty."

I practically never wear [heavy](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heavy_Armor) [armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Armor), so I've only gathered how much it penalizes movement by watching others. I haven't really noticed movement penalization by wearing [light armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Light_Armor) (or maybe it's cause I usually lean towards wearing clothing rather than armour since I never expect to get hit as a hardcore sneaker anyway). And if there's a penalty by wearing clothing too, I'd like to know.

To what degree do each of the types "of apparel that is worn on the body" penalize movement? Do they only penalize movement speed, or attack speed as well? Is it binary such that only wearing one piece of heavy armor brings the maximum penalties of wearing heavy armor?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/43748/43105

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a single source that has hard data on the formula for movement speed. There are a few baseline facts that I've tested and corroborated through other posts online:

- Heavier armor not only slows you down, but causes Sprinting to deplete your endurance faster.
- Clothing does not seem to affect your speed whatsoever - only armor with an actual armor rating counts as light/heavy armor.
- Mixing light/heavy armor also mixes the speed/Sprinting penalty - not sure if each piece contributes 25% or if torso armor contributes more than, say, gloves.
- The total weight of items you're carrying also affects your movement speed - not sure about Sprinting though.
- Having your weapon(s) drawn causes you to move slightly slower.

Sources:

[What are the movement speed effects of walking & running with or without weapon drawn and heavy or light or no armor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37937/in-skyrim-what-are-the-movement-speed-effects-of-walking-running-with-or-with)

http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/737825-armor-weight-effect-on-running-speed-and-endurance/ (has some nice experimental data)